# Git Bash Windows 10 infinite scroll down

Tags: windows, git-bash

I'm using Git Bash on a Windows 10 machine. There's an issue: the cursor does not set the bottom of the terminal window (like in OSX or Linux), I can scroll down infinitely and use the mouse to click and drag any space below the cursor. This causes extra time looking for the cursor if I need to scroll up long rows of commands and their results then need to scroll down.

[image]

In OSX or Linux, you cannot scroll down past the cursor.
I've tried editing Screen Buffer Size but it will just resize the whole window.

Do you have this problem? How would you fix it?